# Why does the content overflow the viewport when doing horizontal and vertical scroll?

Tags: html, css

I do not understand why my HTML content is overflowing the viewport both vertically and horizontally. I can scroll in both directions, even though there is no extra content. I have tried changing the `width` and `height` on the `div` of the parents, but that does not fix the problem. Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 200px;
  font-family: 'Rubik Microbe', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 200px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Megrim', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>SITE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Megrim&family=Rubik+Microbe&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- -->
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>SITE</h1>
    <p>coming soon...</p>
  </main>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have horizontal scroll here : https://codepen.io/yousoumar/pen/gOedbGa.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is `padding-top: 200px;` on the `h1` element. It is not necessary to position elements by using high values of `padding` or `margin`, for example.

So, I took off the padding from `h1` and added flexbox attributes to `body` and your layout works with the `h1` and `p` elements now centered in the page.

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
justify-content: center;
height: 100vh;
```

`height: 100vh;` sets the height of the `body` to the viewport height.

Here, you can find a lot of links to [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flexbox/info), in particular the link to [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) should be of interest.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Rubik Microbe', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 200px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Megrim', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>SITE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Megrim&family=Rubik+Microbe&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- -->
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>SITE</h1>
    <p>coming soon...</p>
  </main>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try `overflow: hidden` in your body section styling.

```
body { overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: Whilst this may get rid of the scroll bars, I would be careful with this answer as it isn't actually going along the lines of solving the issue. But not a bad idea if you want something done quickly whilst you figure something else out. :)